# etymology and pronunciation of bowline knot

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

The wikipedia [article for bowline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline) gives two pronunciations /boʊlɪn/ or /boʊlaɪn/.

The history section says:

> The bowline's name has an earlier meaning, dating to the age of sail.
>   On a square-rigged ship, a bowline (sometimes spelled as two words,
>   bow line) is a rope that holds the edge of a square sail towards the
>   bow of the ship and into the wind, preventing it from being taken
>   aback.

This is what I was expecting; yet, we pronounce it as /boʊ/ not /baʊ/.

The same section goes on to say:

> The bowline knot is thought to have been first mentioned in John
>   Smith's 1691 work A Sea Grammar under the name **Boling** knot.

What does "Boling" refer to? How is it pronounced?
If it is pronounced /boʊlɪŋ/ then I can imagine the 'g' being dropped in usage,
producing /boʊlɪn/, which was somehow applied to the spelling "bowline".

When and why did /boʊlaɪn/ (as opposed to /baʊlaɪn/) become a coherent pronunciation?

-- [IPA](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pronunciation) --

/ɪ/ = i in pit
/аɪ/ = i in ride
/aʊ/ = ow in how
/oʊ/ = o in joke

Comment: I don't have any definitive proof, so this is comment rather than answer, but I saw a Canadian program recently where they referred to the front of a boat as the /boʊ/ bow instead of /baʊ/ like I'm used to.  This may be from the same line of pronunciation.

Comment: You’re not the only person who’s wondered this: the etymological entry for _bowline_ in the OED ends: “In all the Germanic languages it is connected in form with the ship's bow, which seems to be the derivation; though, as it is found in English several centuries before _bow_, it does not appear whence we received it, nor why the pronunciation does not agree with that of _bow_.”

Comment: Working a little bit with sailboats, I've only ever heard "bow-lyn", where "bow" is pronounced like the thing with a ribbon, and "lyn" is pronounced like the female name "Lynn".  The second syllable is sort of swallowed, in the nautical style.

Answer (score 5):

There is strong evidence that Norse people (Vikings) developed the technology of a line from the forward curve of a square sail, to use their longships closer to the wind, before 900 CE. Initially they used poles into cringles on the forward leech, and later the poles were superseded by lines (ropes).

It is not known with certainty what the Norse people first called these lines, but by 1155 CE Wace used *boëline* in Roman de Brut, and words that sounded similar were used by sailors throughout Northern Europe (bowline in modern English). Probably *boë* referred to the curve (bow, *pron. boʊ*) of the sail, as bowlines sometimes ran to tacking poles arranged to the side of the vessel, and other ropes (including standing rigging for the mast) led to the front stem (later known also as the bow, *pron. baʊ*).

At least some longships had hooks to attach bowlines to sails, but it is not known if other forms of attachment were used. On multi-masted tall ships, bowlines and their bridles were attached routinely by splices, seized clinches and toggles; not by fixed-eye knots. In all European languages other than English, the seized clinch (*ABOK* #1130) is also known as the bowline knot (*noeud de bouline, buleinstich, bouglin-steeg, bolinstek, buelta de bolina, boelyn-steek, volta di borina, nó de bolina* etc). But in English only, some confusion arose whereby ‘bowline knot’ became the common name for a fixed-eye knot (*ABOK* #1010). There is no historical evidence that *ABOK* #1010 was used routinely on bowlines, though it would serve well temporarily in an emergency.

Square sails with bowlines are now historical items, but *ABOK* #1010 (*noeud ďagui à élingue, noeud de chaise, liebknoten, psahl-stich, livknob, pael-steeg, lifknop, pålstek, afa de guia, balzo, lyfknoop, paal-steek, volta di quarnara, boca de lobo* etc) is widely used on land and at sea as an easily-tied, readily-verified and jam-resistant fixed eye in cordage.

For a fuller (referenced) analysis, see also "The Stolen Bowline Knot Name" under Knotting at https://www.scithings.id.au/ or download it direct as https://scithings.id.au/Bowline_Name.pdf

Comment: You should have linked [here](http://members.iinet.net.au/~jorobbirch/Bowline_Name.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

***John Smith, 'boling', and the 'boling knot'***

The term *Boling knot* appears in John Smith, [*A Sea Grammar: With the Plaine Exposition of Smiths Accidence for young Sea-men, enlarged*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1BQSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%22Boling+knot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHobXwvcXQAhVmi1QKHdWyAtIQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22Boling%20knot%22&f=false), published not in 1691 (as the Wikipedia article on [bowline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowline) erroneously states) but in 1627. Here is the relevant paragraph from Smith's *Grammar*:

> Now to make an end  of this discourse with a knot, you are to know, Sea-men use three, the first is called the Wall knot, which is a round knob, so made with the strouds or layes of a rope, it cannot slip; the Sheates, Takes, and Stoppers use this knot. The **Boling knot** is also so firmely made and fastened by the bridles knot. into the creengles of the sailes, they will breake, or the saile split before it will slip. The last is the Shepshanke, which is a knot they cast upon a Runner or Tackle when it is too long to take in the goods, and by this knot they can shorten a rope without cutting it, as much as they list, and presently undoe it againe, and yet never the worse.

Elsewhere in the same chapter of the *Grammar* (titled  "How all the Tackling and Rigging of a Ship is made fast one to another, with their names, and the reasons of their use"), Smith discusses the function of the *boling* itself:

> The **Boling** is made fast to the leech of the saile about the middest to make it stand the sharper or closer by a wind, it is fastened by two, three, or foure ropes like a crows foot to as many parts of the saile which is called the **Boling** bridles, onely the missen **Boling** is fastened to the lower end of the yard, this rope belongs to all sailes except the Spret-saile, and Spret-saile Top-saile, which not having any place to hale it forward by, they cannot use those sailes by a wind : sharp the maine **Boling** is to hall it taught : hale up the **Boling** is to pull it harder forward on : checke or ease the **Boling** is to let it be more slacke.

This John Smith is most familiar to people today as the Englishman in the Pocahontas story. Smith uses the word *line* in the sense of "rope" multiple times in the course of the *Grammar*, and he identifies certain specific types of rigging in compounds that use that spelling: *leech lines*, *Knave- line*, *smiting line*, *clew line*, *rayling lines*, *Dipsie line*, *Log line*, *Sounding line*. The three exceptions to this usual pattern are *boling*, *ratling* ("all those small ropes doe crosse the Shrouds like steps are called Ratlings"), and *marling* ("Marling is a small line of untwisted hemp, very pliant and well tarred, to sease the ends of ropes raveling out, or on the sides of the blockes at their arses").

As for *bow*, Smith spells that word in his *Grammar* as you'd expect him to when it stands alone, as in the chapter on ship building:

> It were not amisse now to remember the Fore-castle, being as usefull a place as the rest, this is the forepart of the Ship above the Decks over the **Bow** ; there is a broad **Bow** & a narrow **Bow**, so called according to the broadnes or the thinnesse : the **Bow** is the broadest part of the Ship before, compassing the Stem to the Loufe, which reacheth so farre a the Bulk-head of the Fore-castle extendeth. Against the **Bow** is the first breach of the Sea, if the **Bow** be too broad, she will seldome carry a fome before her : where a well **bowed** Ship so swiftly presseth the water, as that it foameth, and in the darke night sparkleth like fire. If the **Bow** be too narrow, as before is said, she pitcheth her head into the Sea, so that the meane is the best if her after way be answerable.

Of course, this spelling provides no clear indication as to whether the normal pronunciation of *bow* in Smith's time rhymed with "how" or with "low."

If a *bowline* is (as *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* reports) "a rope used to keep the weather edge of a square sail taut forward"—that is, toward the bow—there is little reason for Smith to have preferred the spelling *boling* over *bow line* unless (in 1627) "boling" closely approximated the standard sea-man's pronunciation of the term at that time. This in turn would suggest that the pronunciation **'bō-lən** (to use Merriam-Webster's system of pronunciation symbols), which the *Eleventh Collegiate* gives as the more common pronunciation of *bowline* today (**'bō-<sub><sub>'</sub></sub>līn** is the only other named variant) was already very nearly in place in English speech in 1627.

---

***Other early matches for 'boling', 'bow-line', and 'bowline'***

*Boling* also appears (and *bowline* does not) in Elisha Coles, [*An English Dictionary: Explaining the Difficult Terms that are used in Divinity, Husbandry, Physick, Philosophy, Law, Navigation, Mathematicks, and Other Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=n_5mAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP44&dq=%22Boling+the+cord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTg5Hl6MXQAhUQ52MKHcFnBmoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Boling%20the%20cord%22&f=false) (1676):

> Boling, *the Cord that draws the sail to gather wind*.

This same entry, with minor changes in capitalization, also appears in editions of Coles as late as [1732](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lk1gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT37&dq=%22Boling+the+cord%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTg5Hl6MXQAhUQ52MKHcFnBmoQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22Boling%20the%20cord%22&f=false).

Nathaniel Bailey, [*Dictionarium Britannicum: Or a More Compleat Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CoRZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP111&dq=%22bow+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii_6206sXQAhVD1WMKHTIbDuoQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22bow%20line%22&f=false) (1730), however, lists two spellings—*bow-line* and *bowling*:

> **BOW-LINE**, **BOWLING** {with *Mariners*} a rope made fast to the leetch of the outside of a sail, by 2, 3, or 4 other ropes, like a crow's foot, which is called the ***Bowling** bridle*. Its use is to make the sails stand sharp or close by a wind.
>
> **BOWLING *Knot*** {with *Sailors*} a sort of knot that will not slip, by which the **bowling** bridle is fastened to the crengles.

However, Bailey's [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=R_xIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP118&dq=%22bow+line%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii_6206sXQAhVD1WMKHTIbDuoQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22bow%20line%22&f=false), second edition (1731) drops the entries for *bowline/bowling* and for *bowling knot*, and retains only a brief three-part entry for *check the bowline*, *ease the bowline*, and *run up the bowline*, defined as "{*Sea* terms} which import, let it be more slack."

The earliest match for the spelling "bowline knot" is from Daniel Baron Lescallier, [*Vocabulaire des termes de marine anglois et françois*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YNG8TV4HB7gC&pg=PA41&dq=%22bowline+knot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf7-Sy3MXQAhVaHGMKHa10Cj8Q6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=%22bowline%20knot%22&f=false) (1777), a French-English dictionary of nautical terms:

> Bowline-knot, *Nœud de bouline*.

But an English-Swedish dictionary from 20 years early has no compunction about switching from *bowline* to *boling-knot* in the same block of phrase translations. From Jacob Serenius, [*An English and Swedish Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ff9YAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP633&dq=%22bowline%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq0t6S4cXQAhWDKGMKHYppADYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22bowline%22&f=false) (1757):

> BOWLINE, *bog-lina*. Hale up the bowline, *holl an bog-linan*, *hala up bog-linan*. Ease the Bowline, *fyr på bog-linan*. Sharp the Bowline, *drag hårdare til bog-linan*. Bowling-knot, *en hård knut*, *som icke går up igen eller losnar*.

Even earlier, Daniel Defoe, in Letter 53 of [*Miscellany Letters: Selected out of Mist's Weekly Journal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8S5WAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA159&dq=%22bowline%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqyIar48XQAhXIKWMKHU4UD984KBDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22bowline%22&f=false) (1722) opens one with the salutation "Mist, you Haul-Bowline Dog..."

William Falconer, [*An Universal Dictionary of the Marine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3pVAAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22bowline%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpr7aJ5cXQAhXEMGMKHfcyC1o4PBDoAQg1MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bowline%22&f=false) (1784) has multiple instances of *bowline*, including this entry for the term:

> **BOWLINE** (*boulin*, Fr.) a rope fastened near the middle of the leech, or perpendicular edge of the square sails, by three or four subordinate parts called bridles. It is only used when the  wind is so unfavourable that the sails must all be braced sideways, or close-hauled to the wind : in this situation the **bowlines** are employed to keep the weather, or windward, edges of the principal sails tight forward and steady, without which they would be always shivering, and rendered incapable of service.

Comment: For a fuller (referenced) analysis see also "The Stolen Bowline Knot Name" under Knotting at http://members.iinet.net.au/~jorobbirch

Answer (score -2):

John Smith either misheard *[bowline](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bowline)* (ˈbəʊlɪn) and attributed it to a person, or *Boling* simply reflects the lack of standardization in spelling that was prevalent.

I would pronounce *Boling* like *[bowling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bowling)* (ˈbəʊlɪŋ), which isn't too far off the British pronunciation of *bowline* (ˈbəʊlɪn) (as opposed to the [US English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bowline) ˈboulīn).

Comment: What is this American ˈboulīn? Is it like IPA /boʊlɪn/ ? (see the OP's key)

Comment: @Mitch No, it’s IPA /ˈboʊˌlaɪn/.

Comment: Added a link to Oxford's US English pronunciation of [_bowline_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bowline)

Comment: [Americans](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bowline) pronounce it /boʊlɪn/, too. At least the ones who sail.

Comment: and Boy Scouts learning their knots

Comment: Gnawme, with all due respect to OED, they are wrong. The accepted AmE pronunciation is like BrE. Strangely, that entry says that it rhymes with 'pangolin', which as far as the last syllable is right, but inconsistent with the pronunciation link.

Comment: @Mitch M-W Unabridged lists /ˈboulīn/ as an acceptable _secondary_ pronunciation, so OED isn't entirely wrong.

Comment: The same knot is used for many purposes, not least for the ends of the string of an archery bow where they fit into the notches in the ends of the limbs of the bow. The fixed loop of the bowline knot is important when the bow is unbraced as the top loop of the string must be big enough to slide down the tapered top limb. Bows predate ships (I suspect that bowline knots predate bows) and sailors were very familiar with archery bows. I suspect, but have no proof (hence this is a comment), that the line is named after the knot which is named after the weapon.

Comment: @Gnawme: Americans who don't sail often say *mane-sale* and not *mainsl*, *four-castle* and not *fokesl*, *boy* and not *boo-ee*, and so forth. In short, they pronounce all nautical terms wrong. And dictionaries list these mispronunciations as acceptable secondary pronunciations.

Comment: (Okay, *buoy* is pronounced both ways by sailors, partly depending on where in the U.S. they live. But I don't think the spelling pronunciations of *mainsail, forecastle,* and *bowline* are ever used in the U.S. by people familiar with boats.)